# Hot to partially render a voxel object?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, 3d, 3d-rendering

I do have 3D array[250][150][250] which represents human body (basically it is a voxel object). Each element contain values from 0 to 255, where 255 means that an elements is empty and should be ignored and 0-254 represent different organs (like skin, lung and etch) hence should be drawn. In my program I writing the data of elements that should be drawn in 2 txt files (vertices.txt and indices.txt). vertices.txt contain x,y and z coordinates of all voxel vertices that should be drawn and indices.txt contain all indices.

I am able to render whole body with all organs that is not the problem.[image]

Example from vertices.txt:

```
193 68 0 // coordinates of a voxel
193 68 1
193 69 0
193 69 1
```

Example from indices.txt:

```
4 5 7 4 6 7  // face of a voxel. Each face is represented by 2 triangles. Hence, we need 6 indices.
2 3 7 2 6 7
0 4 6 0 2 6
```

My problem is that I do not know how to render a specific part of a body (For example: lets say that I want to render only lungs). How can I do that? Do I have to create indices.txt and vetices.txt for each individual organ (basically making each organ as a separate mesh)?

EDIT: Code that is responsible for writing into vertices.txt and indices.txt.

```
void writePhantomDataToThefile(std::ofstream& verticies_out_file, std::ofstream& indicies_out_file)
{
    verticies_out_file.open(vertices, std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::trunc);
    indicies_out_file.open(indices, std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::trunc);

    unsigned elements = 0;

    for (int z = 0; z < zMax; z++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < yMax; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < xMax; x++)
            {
                if (phantom->voxel[x][y][z] == emptyVoxel) // empty voxel is 255
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    if ((x != 0 && x != (xMax - 1)) && (y != 0 && y != (yMax - 1)) && (z != 0 && z != (zMax - 1)) &&
                        (phantom->voxel[x + 1][y][z] != emptyVoxel) && (phantom->voxel[x - 1][y][z] != emptyVoxel) && (phantom->voxel[x][y + 1][z] != emptyVoxel) &&
                        (phantom->voxel[x][y - 1][z] != emptyVoxel) && (phantom->voxel[x][y][z + 1] != emptyVoxel) && (phantom->voxel[x][y][z - 1] != emptyVoxel))
                    { // this part of code skips elements if is surrounded by elements != 255
                        continue; // basically right now I am drawing the skin of a body
                    }

                    verticies_out_file << x << " " << y << " " << z << std::endl;
                    verticies_out_file << x << " " << y << " " << z + 1 << std::endl;
                    verticies_out_file << x << " " << y + 1 << " " << z << std::endl;
                    verticies_out_file << x << " " << y + 1 << " " << z + 1 << std::endl;
                    verticies_out_file << x + 1 << " " << y << " " << z << std::endl;
                    verticies_out_file << x + 1 << " " << y << " " << z + 1 << std::endl;
                    verticies_out_file << x + 1 << " " << y + 1 << " " << z << std::endl;
                    verticies_out_file << x + 1 << " " << y + 1 << " " << z + 1 << std::endl;

                    if (x != 0 && x != (xMax - 1))
                    {
                        if (phantom->voxel[x - 1][y][z] != emptyVoxel)
                        {
                            indicies_out_file << (elements * 8) << " " << (elements * 8 + 2) << " " << (elements * 8 + 3) << " "
                            << (elements * 8) << " " << (elements * 8 + 1) << " "<< (elements * 8 + 3) << std::endl; // left face
                        }
                        if (phantom->voxel[x + 1][y][z] != emptyVoxel)
                        {
                            indicies_out_file << (elements * 8 + 4) << " " << (elements * 8 + 5) << " "<< (elements * 8 + 7) << " " 
                            << (elements * 8 + 4) << " "<< (elements * 8 + 6) << " " << (elements * 8 + 7) << std::endl; // right face
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (x == 0)
                        {
                            indicies_out_file << (elements * 8) << " " << (elements * 8 + 2) << " "<< (elements * 8 + 3) << " "
                            << (elements * 8) << " "<< (elements * 8 + 1) << " "<< (elements * 8 + 3) << std::endl; // left face
                        }
                        if (x == (xMax - 1))
                        {
                            indicies_out_file << (elements * 8 + 4) << " "<< (elements * 8 + 5) << " "<< (elements * 8 + 7) << " "
                            << (elements * 8 + 4) << " " << (elements * 8 + 6) << " " << (elements * 8 + 7) << std::endl; // right face
                        }
                    }

                    if (y != 0 && y != (yMax - 1))
                    {
                        if (phantom->voxel[x][y - 1][z] != emptyVoxel)
                        {
                            indicies_out_file << (elements * 8 + 1) << " " << (elements * 8 + 5) << " "<< (elements * 8 + 4) << " " 
                            << (elements * 8 + 1) << " " << (elements * 8) << " "<< (elements * 8 + 4) << std::endl; // bottom face
                        }
                        if (phantom->voxel[x][y + 1][z] != emptyVoxel)
                        {
                            indicies_out_file << (elements * 8 + 2) << " " << (elements * 8 + 3) << " " << (elements * 8 + 7) << " " 
                            << (elements * 8 + 2) << " " << (elements * 8 + 6) << " " << (elements * 8 + 7) << std::endl; // top face
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (y == 0)
                        {
                            indicies_out_file << (elements * 8 + 1) << " " << (elements * 8 + 5) << " " << (elements * 8 + 4) << " " 
                            << (elements * 8 + 1) << " " << (elements * 8) << " " << (elements * 8 + 4) << std::endl; // bottom face
                        }

                        if (y == (yMax - 1))
                        {
                            indicies_out_file << (elements * 8 + 2) << " " << (elements * 8 + 3) << " " << (elements * 8 + 7) << " " 
                            << (elements * 8 + 2) << " " << (elements * 8 + 6) << " " << (elements * 8 + 7) << std::endl; // top face
                        }
                    }

                    if (z != 0 && z != (zMax - 1))
                    {
                        if (phantom->voxel[x][y][z - 1] != emptyVoxel)
                        {
                            indicies_out_file << (elements * 8) << " " << (elements * 8 + 4) << " " << (elements * 8 + 6) << " " 
                            << (elements * 8) << " " << (elements * 8 + 2) << " " << (elements * 8 + 6) << std::endl;  // front face
                        }

                        if (phantom->voxel[x][y][z + 1] != emptyVoxel)
                        {
                            indicies_out_file << (elements * 8 + 1) << " " << (elements * 8 + 5) << " " << (elements * 8 + 7) << " "
                            << (elements * 8 + 1) << " " << (elements * 8 + 3) << " " << (elements * 8 + 7) << std::endl; // back face
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (z == 0)
                        {
                            indicies_out_file << (elements * 8) << " " << (elements * 8 + 4) << " " << (elements * 8 + 6) << " "
                            << (elements * 8) << " " << (elements * 8 + 2) << " " << (elements * 8 + 6) << std::endl;  // front face
                        }

                        if (z == (zMax - 1))
                        {
                            indicies_out_file << (elements * 8 + 1) << " " << (elements * 8 + 5) << " " << (elements * 8 + 7) << " "
                            << (elements * 8 + 1) << " " << (elements * 8 + 3) << " " << (elements * 8 + 7) << std::endl; // back face
                        }
                    }

                    elements++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    verticies_out_file.close();
    indicies_out_file.close();
}
```

Mesh.cpp

```
#include "Mesh.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

Mesh::Mesh()
{
    loaded = false;
}

Mesh::~Mesh()
{
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &ibo);
}

void Mesh::loadVertices(std::string fileName)
{
    int item = 0, n = 0, x = 0, y = 0;
    std::ifstream is(fileName, std::ifstream::binary);

    if (is) {
        is.seekg(0, is.end);
        int length = is.tellg();
        is.seekg(0, is.beg);

        char* buffer = new char[length];

        is.read(buffer, length);

        is.close();

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < is.gcount(); i++)
        {
            switch (buffer[i])
            {
            case '\r':
                break;
            case '\n':
            {
                vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(y, item, x));
                n = 0;
                item = 0;
                break;
            }
            case ' ':
            {
                n++;
                if (n == 1)
                {
                    x = item;
                }
                else
                {
                    y = item;
                }

                item = 0;
                break;
            }
            case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3':
            case '4': case '5': case '6': case '7':
            case '8': case '9':
                item = 10 * item + buffer[i] - '0';
                break;
            default:
                std::cerr << "Bad format\n";
            }
        }

        delete[] buffer;
    }
}

void Mesh::loadIndices(std::string fileName)
{
    int item = 0;
    std::ifstream is(fileName, std::ifstream::binary);

    if (is) {
        is.seekg(0, is.end);
        int length = is.tellg();
        is.seekg(0, is.beg);

        char* buffer = new char[length];

        is.read(buffer, length);

        is.close();

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < is.gcount(); i++)
        {
            switch (buffer[i])
            {
            case '\r':
                break;
            case '\n':
            {
                indicies.push_back(item);
                item = 0;
                break;
            }
            case ' ':
            {
                indicies.push_back(item);
                item = 0;
                break;
            }
            case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3':
            case '4': case '5': case '6': case '7':
            case '8': case '9':
                item = 10 * item + buffer[i] - '0';
                break;
            default:
                std::cerr << "Bad format\n";
            }
        }

        delete[] buffer;
    }
}


bool Mesh::loadOBJ()
{
    loadVertices("Phantom Data/FA_vertices.txt");
    loadIndices("Phantom Data/FA_indices.txt");

    initBuffers();

    return (loaded = true);
}

void Mesh::draw()
{
    if (!loaded) return;


    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indicies.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

void Mesh::initBuffers()
{

    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(glm::vec3), NULL);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glGenBuffers(1, &ibo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicies.size() * sizeof(GLuint), &indicies[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

Comment: That depends : how are your current vertices linked by the indices? If they are roughly linked per organ, you could keep uploading the full set of vertices but map your voxel faces into bins according to the organ, then only render the desired bin. Show the code you use for rendering.

Comment: @Botje I added code for rendering and writing into vertices and indices into txt files. Can you please expand on idea of linking organs with vertices and indices? Because they are not linked in any form. Vertices are just coordinate that should be drawn.

Comment: When you say that voxel values `"0-254 represent different organs (like skin, lung and etch)"` do you mean that each integer value represents a specific organ?  Or is it as is more generally the case that voxel values refer to some measured quantity such as tissue density or whatever?

Comment: @G.M. sorry for confusion. Yes, each integer value represent  a specific organ. Fir example elements with value = to 130 represent skin and so on.

Comment: For starters you can identify voxel faces where all vertices belong to the same organ and create a separate list of indices for each organ.

Comment: @Botje so you mean to create just 1 vertices.txt that will contain all vertices and for each individual organ one indices.txt? If yes, would it better to create for each organ its own indices.txt and vertice.txt as it will give us more flexibility in the case if I need to change color or scale individual organ?

Comment: The program interpreting those two files can take care of all that, just let it filter faces according to their organ type. That also enables you to switch organs on the fly or show multiple organs at once. If filtering the full data set is too slow you could use some optimizations like bounding boxes for organs (so it does not need to consider vertices that are definitely not part of the organ)